# Repetitive copy/pasting with a change in a only a few fields

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

There is a worksheet that I have to create on occasion that I need to constantly copy/paste (default info) and then only change 2/3 fields (with info from another worksheet) in order to populate the worksheet. Because of the repetitiveness I feel like there could be a macro/formula which could greatly improve the speed of this task. Unfortunately, I don't have the required knowledge to make it happen. Can anyone shed some light on this?

The normal process:

1. Start with default template with the 3 changeable fields already filled  (this could be anywhere from 10-200 rows).
2. Copy/paste this template onto the first line underneath template
3. Fill new copy/paste with new information in the 3 fields (from different worksheet) that need changing.
4. Repeat until all changeable fields in other worksheet have been filled in default template worksheet.

Example:

[image]
So for instance, I need to copy/paste the information into those fields that say "Need to be copy/pasted", then copy/paste that template to the next available row then get another value (vendor) from another spreadsheet. Fill the values into the fields again and re-do until all vendors are done in the template. So then it looks likes this...

[image]

And keep doing it until I've done all vendors from the other spreadsheet.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try posting an example of your data and what you are hoping the result will be. That will make it easier to help you.

Comment: You can record the macro and perform the task. It will give you at the very least a good idea on how to code the macro: http://www.dummies.com/software/microsoft-office/excel/how-to-record-a-macro-to-automate-tasks-in-excel-2010/

Comment: We need some examples before we can help you.

Comment: Updated with examples.

Comment: Need to see examples of your source data, and example of how it looks when copied over.  Too broad a question with too many possibilities at this point.